# protractor - using variables into locators

Tags: protractor

I would like to use a variable for an element locator ; I have defined this data structure :

```
CreatorSearch: {
        ...
        inCreatorItem : element (by.xpath('//span[contains(text(),invalue)]')),
        ...
       }
```

then in a function I have tried to use a parameter in the xpath like this:

```
 CreatorInput : function (creator_value, present){
        var screen3 = this.CreatorSearch
        inCreatorItem : element 
       (by.xpath('//span[contains(text(),str.replace(invalue,creator_value))]'))
```

but it seems that does not work , there is another solution or what is wrong in what I wrote ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
element(by.xpath("//span[[contains(text()," + creator_value + ")]"));
```

Comment: Thank you !  Finally I managed to make it work adding the single quote to your solution , like this :
element(by.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'" + creator_value + "')]"));